# Status of the Woocommerce order change from processing to complete after the order is placed with COD?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have an online store where customers place an order and it is done with payment as COD. It is integrated with our warehouse management where it will export all the orders at the end of the day to the system from the site.
The status of the orders places are processing.
I am trying to make a php cron job where the order status of all these order set as completed when the list of orders are exported.

I have looked at various solutions and all change the order status at the time of placing the order while i want it later, once the data is exported.

If somebody can help me with the php function that sets all the order in the woocommerce to "complete" at some trigger, I would be really grateful.

Comment: From where your are exporting order(s)?

Comment: From woocommerce, I am exporting the placed orders.

Comment: from WooCommerce > Reports > Orders, then Export CSV right? so need to find the hook that trigger when this report is generated.

Comment: Hi Raunak, Nope, its custom csv thing again based on cron job again.

Comment: Then you have the answer, in that cron job call a custom function which 'll update the order status to `wc-complete`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and i am looking for hook that is required to send the data to pre-existing order to mark that status complete?

Answer (score 0):

In your cron function you may have a loop to get the order ID that needs to be exported, so just pass the Order ID to the given function it'll update the Order Status to `wc-complete`, you can also pass an order note if you need.

```
function wh_mark_order_as_omplete($order_id, $note = '')
{
    //this check is option if you do not need this you can remove it.
    //for COD order only
    if ('cod' != get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true))
        return;

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if (empty($note)):
        $order->update_status('completed');
    else:
        $order->update_status('completed', $note);
    endif;
}
```

Hope this helps!